# Scraping Blogs - avoid already scraped items by checking urls from json/csv in advance

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I'd like to scrape newspages / blogs (anything, which contains new informations on a daily basis).

My Crawler works fine and does everything, I kindly asked him to do.

But I cannot find a proper solution to the circumstance, that I'd like him to ignore already scraped urls (or items to keep it more general) and just add new urls/items to an already existing json/csv file.

I've seen many solutions here to check, whether an item exists in a csv file.. but none of this "solutions" did really work.

Scrapy DeltaFetch seems to cannot be installed on my system... I've get errors af. and all the hints, like e.g. $ sudo pip install bsddb3, upgrade this and update that.. etc.. does not do the trick. (tried it for 3 hours now and fed up with solutionfinding for a package, which wasn't updated since 2017).

I hope, that you have a handy and practical solution.

Thank you very much in advance!

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option could be a custom [downloader middleware](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html) with the following:

- A process_response that puts the url you crawled in a database
- A process_request method that checks if the url is present in the database. If it's in there, you raise an IgnoreRequest so the request is not going through anymore.

Comment: Thank you! Can you provide me an existing example of a similar task, so that I can understand the logic behind it? I am pretty new to really write my code from ground on. Therefore I am in need of a helping hand ....

Comment: I think the closest thing to this is the httpcache in the downloader middleware of Scrapy library: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/downloadermiddlewares/httpcache.py